# How do I stop Azure CI from retrying infinitely?

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

How do you stop a pipeline from automatically running after every failed run? We have an hourly build that is triggered by a push to main, but it also gets triggered when the last run failed. How do I stop this from happening? It causes the pipeline to retry the run throughout the night, or even over the weekend and that can be problematic.

This is what we have for scheduling/triggering right now.

```yaml
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - main

schedules:
  - cron: "0 * * * *" 
    displayName: Hourly builds
    branches:
      include: 
      - main
```

Comment: There's nothing out of the box. I'd look at adding a step that triggers on `condition: failure()` that disables the pipeline via REST API calls.